How to search for the acronym of a string column in an indexable way
I'm working on an express.js project, using Sequelize as the orm, and postgres as the engine.
I'm working on improving the performance of a slow select query that does many things, and one of them is comparing the acronym of the name of the warehouse against a search term using ilike, so if the search term is "STW", a warehouse named "Super Test Warehouse" will match. The query looks like this:
SELECT field1, field2, ...
FROM package p
LEFT OUTER JOIN warehouse w ON p.warehouse_id = w.id
-- many other joins
WHERE
    regexp_replace(w.name, '([a-z ])+', '', 'g') ILIKE '%search term%'
    -- many other conditions

The thing is, the main improvement I'm doing is creating indexes (gin for everything that does ilike '%something%'), and refactoring the query to be able to use them. But the regexp_replace() function doesn't work with indexes. Another important thing to note is that this solution only works if all the words in the names are correctly capitalized, which is the case with most of our data, but not all, so if there's a warehouse named "Super TEST Warehouse", or "super test Warehouse", it won't work correctly.
A simple solution I thought of, is to do this (assuming the search text is "STW"):
w.name ILIKE 'S% T% W%' OR w.name ILIKE '% S% T% W%'

It works on the average case, and it uses the gin index I created. But the problem is that it allows other words in between. So "STW" would also match "Super Fake Test Warehouse".
Is there any condition that would match the acronym correctly, and would use an index?
Would you recommend using a generated column for this (assuming I improve the existing regexp_replace, or use something else)? Are there any downsides of doing that? Ideally, I don't want to alter a table only for this feature, but could be a good solution if there's nothing else we can do.
Any other solutions?

Maybe add an acronym column - indexed - to table warehouse  and fill it with regexp_replace("name", '[^A-Z]', '', 'g') as default? Then your searches will be fast. If your data domain does not allow alter table then you may create a separate table wh_name_acronym and join with it.

You better create a column for the acronym and index over that. I concur with first comment.

"But the regexp_replace function doesn't work with indexes"  Why doesn't it?  What error do you get?

Why do you mean by "error"? How would I even get an error using indexes? When I do explain analyze of the query with the regexp_replace, it doesn't use the gin index I created, it does a seq scan, and according to what I've read, no index is going to help with something like that. Was that a generic response to make people put more info in the responses?

When something "doesn't work", it usually throws an error.  But I can't guess every possible way there is for something to "not work", that is why it is upon you explain it.  So yes, I guess it is a generic response to get you to explain what you mean.  It does work for me to get the index to be used, although the regexp pattern itself could use some improvement, possibly like what Erwin shows in his answer.

What I'm doing in the end is making a generated column like this:
ALTER TABLE warehouse
ADD COLUMN name_acronym TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    array_to_string(
        array(
            SELECT substring(word FROM 1 FOR 1)
            FROM unnest(string_to_array(name, ' ')) AS word
        ),
        ''
    )
) STORED;

I also have this index for name:
CREATE INDEX warehouse_name ON warehouse USING gin ("name" gin_trgm_ops);

First, this solution is more accurate for the acronyms, since it actually takes the first letter of each word. And also, ilike queries against the generated column will make use the index.


Ideally, I don't want to alter a table only for this feature

So create an expression index:
CREATE INDEX foo ON package (upper(regexp_replace(name, '\W*?\m(.).*?\M', '\1', 'g')));

The expression extracts upper-case acronyms reliably (except for trailing non-word characters in your strings):
SELECT upper(regexp_replace('SUPER ware hOUse', '\W*?\m(.).*?\M', '\1', 'g'));  -- SWH

The involved functions are immutable, so fit for an expression index.
Repeat the expression in your queries to bring in the index:
SELECT *
FROM   package p
WHERE  upper(regexp_replace(name, '\W*?\m(.).*?\M', '\1', 'g')) = 'SWH';

I would prefer to add a generated column, though. Simpler query and a bit faster, yet, for only very few added bytes per row. See:

Computed / calculated / virtual / derived / generated columns in PostgreSQL

